# How can I connect Philips Hue to a guest network on my AirPort Extreme?

Tags: network, wifi, airport

Would I be able to get a Philips Hue system on a guest network somehow? [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51934/28217) leads me to believe I won't be able to connect it with ethernet, but is there a way to connect it wirelessly?

My network setup is pretty straightforward:

- Cable modem
- Apple AirPort Extreme, creating a main and guest network

  - Main network

    - Apple AirPort Express to extend network
  - Guest network

    - Philips Hue?

Answer (score 1):

As a sort of workaround, you could use [a wireless-to-Ethernet bridge](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202056) to let your Hue access the guest WiFi network. The AirPort Express can do this, but [not while still acting as an extender](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5473124?start=0&tstart=0).